# Generating pdf document

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to generate a PDF document using laravel, I am getting  the following error:
`Missing required parameters for [Route: assignees.pdf] [URI: assignees/downloadPDF].` When trying to download the pdf document.

**My view**:

```
<a href="{{ route('assignees.pdf',$assignees)}}">Download Report as PDF</a>
```

**My Controller**:

```
public function pdf(Assignee $assignees){

  $pdf = PDF::loadView('assignees.report', compact('assignees'));
  return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');

}
```

**My route**:

```
Route::get('assignees/downloadPDF','AssigneeController@pdf')->name('assignees.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no specified any route param, check this :

```
Route::get('{assignee}/downloadPDF','AssigneeController@pdf')->name('assignees.pdf');
```

Above will have url like `url.com/1/downloadPDF`
And in blade :

(Considering you have assignee id already in `$assignee` variable)

```
<a href="{{ route('assignees.pdf', compact('assignee'))}}">Download Report as PDF</a>
```

Also, [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding) works for a single model instance. So you can pass an assignee id and as you have type hint of `Assignee $assignees` in controller, Laravel will give you an Assignee for that id.

Comment: The page i am calling the link from already have the object” assignees ” with multiple entries, i am not sure why should i generate the same variable in the controller”pdf” again.

Comment: You can not pass an object in the URL param like that. Either you can post the data or have id of the asignee.